# Treeline.io - How to parse json from SendHTTPRequest

Tags: treeline

I'm retrieving json from my SendHTTPRequest

[image]

It looks like this (in the browser)

```
{
status: 200,
headers: "{"server":"nginx","date":"Thu, 23 Apr 2015 15:13:44 GMT","content-type":"application/json; charset=utf-8","transfer-encoding":"chunked","connection":"keep-alive","x-source":"redis","access-control-allow-origin":"*","access-control-allow-credentials":"true","access-control-allow-methods":"GET, POST"}",
body: "{"coord":{"lon":-0.13,"lat":51.51},"sys":{"message":0.0112,"country":"GB","sunrise":1429764429,"sunset":1429816225},"weather":[{"id":800,"main":"Clear","description":"Sky is Clear","icon":"01d"}],"base":"stations","main":{"temp":289.343,"temp_min":289.343,"temp_max":289.343,"pressure":1023.31,"sea_level":1031.3,"grnd_level":1023.31,"humidity":56},"wind":{"speed":1.52,"deg":110},"clouds":{"all":0},"dt":1429801539,"id":2643743,"name":"London","cod":200}"
}
```

Not sure how to use it in the ParseJSON machine

What exactly should go in `json:` and `schema:`?

I get a status: 500 Internal service error with this. (Note, I also tried the Send HTTP Request body variable, but then I just see a blank screen w/)

[image]

Comment: If you click the blue "Send HTTP request" bubble it should have a dropdown where you can select the body attribute.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `schema` input of the Parse JSON machine allows any type, but it looks like you want it to return a dictionary.  At the moment there's no way to paste dictionaries into the input--what you've done is pasted in a string, so the machine will return a string.  If you want it to return a dictionary, you'll have to specify it yourself by first wiping out the string you pasted into `schema`, then typing a `{` character to start the dictionary, and then typing all of the keys and example values that the resulting output from `Parse JSON` should have.

Also as @particlebanana said you can dereference a bubble that represents a dictionary (such as the output from "Send HTTP request") by clicking on it and selecting one of its properties.

Comment: Thanks! This is pretty painful! But I understand as a beta, look forward to when ya'll make this as easy as copy and paste